# square numbers given in an sequence

Tags: algorithm, big-o

Given a positive integer sequence of numbers in an array with common difference 2
for e.g 2 4 6 8
Now replace each number by its square. Perform the computations efficiently.
I was asked this question in an interview and i gave him o(n) solution using bitwise operator since it is operation in the multiples of 2.If there is any better method please suggest.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "replace each number by its square?"  My understanding is that this must take &Omega;(n) time, since you have to visit every element of the array at least once to update it.  What specifically are you try to optimize?

Comment: @above yeah the same approach i have done.. i just wanted to know is there any way to square a number better than doing it with bit wise operator.

Comment: Ummmmm... I'm not sure I get your squaring algorithm. Would you be willing to explain it? Specifically how you use bitwise ops?

Comment: Yah I'm with Hack Saw; not sure how "bitwise operator" is going to help you be more efficient here unless you're talking about aaa's / Chris Schmich's approach

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I dunno if its better but it's recursive!!! :-)

```
(n+2)(n+2) = n**2 + 4*n + 4 // and you got n**2
```

Comment: @aaa: Heh, sorry, deleted my comment, was just going to edit :)

Comment: +1 - I think this was what the interviewer was getting at.  However, I doubt that a program that exploits this is going to be any faster than one that uses simple multiplication ... assuming that the numbers are represented using a primitive integer type.  IMO, this is a pretty lame question ... unless the aim is to *weed out* people who provide "clever" answers.

Comment: @aaa i think this was the interviewer was expecting...:)

Comment: @Stephen I think you're right but it depends on how long that array is (how big those numbers get).  In an interview the right answer should be "and then test it on the hardware you're going to use".

Answer (score 0):

```
class Square
{
  public static int[] sequence(int[] array)
  {
    int[] result=new int[array.length];
    for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++)
    {
      result[i]=array[i]*array[i];
    }
    return result;
  }
}

// test cases:
// Square.sequence(new int[]{2,4,6,8})
//out put->{ 4, 16, 36, 64 }
```

Comment: please elaborate your appraoch and how it is better.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the interviewer, and what they think is "the right thing". If it were me, I'd think the (n << 2) + 4 were neat, but on the other hand, I'd hate to see it in my code. It takes more thinking to maintain, and there's a fair chance a good optimizer might do just as good a job.

I think the phrase "perform the operation efficiently" is probably our clue that the interviewer was looking for a fast computation. It's still O(n), but let's not forget that when you are comparing two O(n) algorithms, the coefficients start to matter again.